# Good books on undergraduate regression analysis that focus on math derivation of the formula

Tags: regression

Good books on undergraduate regression analysis that focus on math derivation of the regression formula instead just given out the formula as a definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the book Linear Models in Statistics (2nd ed.) by Alvin C. Rencher, G. Bruce Schaalje.  It would probably be a more advanced undergraduate text and requires knowledge of Matrix Algebra.  I'd encourage you to check it out and to see if it is at your level as undergraduate abilities vary considerably from institution to institution and person to person.

Answer (score 1):

**Verbeek (2012). A Guide to Modern Econometrics. Wiley**. The *practical examples* that come with the book are suited for finance/economics, but there are derivations of most statistical theory that is used within this field, such as regression analysis, logistic regression, panel regression, etc. I would not say it constitutes as an undergraduate book, though. You have to be fairly skilled at mathematics to understand this book as it assumes you have some basic prior knowledge about statistics. But I assume you have this as you are interested in the derivations of the theory.